# Windowing function in My-Sql does not work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, max, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have three columns in a my-sql table: Id, name and mark. All rows are distinct with each other.
I use the below sql statements. Inside the windowing function, I don't use order by in both the SQL statements. I have only partition and range frame.

Ideally they should give same results under the derived column from windowing function; but the first one always gives the maximum mark under the window; whereas the second one compares the previous row and current row+1 and gives the expected result. The first one is really weird even though I give unbounded preceding and current row; It in fact, considers the whole window rather than the given frame.

Can someone please help.

**Statement-1:**

```
select  *
       ,max(mark) over( partition by name   rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as w_f 
from  ( select * from student order by name, mark asc) a
```

**Statement-2:**

```
select  *
       ,max(mark) over( partition by name   rows between 1 preceding and 1 following) as w_f 
from  ( select * from student order by name, mark asc) a
```

Answer (score 1):

A row (or range) frame without an `order by` clause does not make sense: how do you define which row is preceding or following if you don't specify which column(s) should be used for ordering.

Also note that the subquery the `order by` clause probably does not do what you expect it to do. There is no guarantee that the inner sort propagate to the outer query whatsoever.

In absence of sample data and desired results, it is a bit unclear what you actually are trying to do. Assuming that you have ordering column `id`, the first query would phrase as:

```
select s.*,
    max(mark) over(partition by name rows order by id) as w_f 
from student
order by name, id
```

`rows between unbounded preceding and current row` is the default window specification (actually that's `range between ...`, which is equivalent if you have a unique sorting key).

And the second query would go like:

```
select s.*,
    max(mark) over(partition by name rows order by id rows between 1 preceding and 1 following) as w_f 
from student
order by name, id
```